# compare on number of awk result is not correct

Tags: awk

I use `awk` to get the number of fields for multiple files, and then use `if [[ ]]` to judge whether the number of fields equal to an exact number, if so, then return the file name.

The code is as follows:

```
for file in /root/TB_MOVIL_CDR/incorrect_files/*
do
  num=$(awk -F '|' '{print NF}' $file)
  if [[ $num -eq 24 ]];then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

But if found the result is not correct, I am confused, 
the syntax of `if [[ $num -eq 24 ]]` is wrong ?

Comment: `[[ $num -eq 24 ]]` is fine, but if your files have more than one line, you will be filling `num` with more than one number which will make `[[ $num -eq 24 ]]` choke...

Comment: oh, i got your point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need for bash commands when you do use `awk`, try this:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==24 {print FILENAME}' /root/TB_MOVIL_CDR/incorrect_files/*
```

This will test if number of fields are 24 in each line of each file, and if it finds a line with 24 fields, it will print the file name.   NB if there are several files with 24 fields it print filename multiple times.  This can be avoided if needed.

You can use this `gnu awk` to print the file name only once for each file with 24 fields (gnu due to the ENDFILE function):

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==24 {f=1} ENDFILE {if (f) print FILENAME;f=0}' /root/TB_MOVIL_CDR/incorrect_files/*
```

A shorter `gnu awk` that print file name once for each file.

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==24 {print FILENAME;nextfile}' /root/TB_MOVIL_CDR/incorrect_files/*
```